# How to browse sqlite data in xamarin?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view in my app, some data is saving to the database before populating list view.

My problem is that can't see the data, and how to verify the data is stored in the database.

Answer (score 6):

I am giving the solution for Visual Studio 2015 (worked for Xamarin).

[image: Tools-Android-Android Device Monitor]

[image]

- Locate the database file mentioned in above image, and click on Pull button as it shown in image 2.
- Save the file in your desired location.
- You can open that file using SQLite Studio or DB Browser for SQLite to verify your data is saved.

Comment: It's not a solution if you don't have your device rooted

Answer (score 4):

You can use use a SQLite browser, such as the open-source multi-platform [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org), or another tool of your choice.

Getting access to the sqlite file is the next thing:

**iOS Simulator:**

```
/Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator
```

You can browse simulator files from that directory in Mac OS X.

**Android Emulator:**

You can use the command line via `adb shell` command for browsing file system:

```
ls - list current directory 
cd - change current directory
```

Once you find the Sqlite file for your app, you can use the `pull` cmd for copying the file from device (or emulator image):

```
adb pull /sdcard/file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: I'm using Genymotion emulator hope the same procedure do with this too , i'm using xamarin.forms android in win 8 pc  @RobertN i

Comment: ALL Android emulators use `adb` in some way, no way around it, Genymotion packages a specific version or your can use the latest one from Google : https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support?chapter=adb-connection

Comment: This worked for me on Android, with some extra step. I have to run "adb root" before running "adb pull..." and when finish i run "adb unroot" (i heard some may have issues debugging in VS if not unroot)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem in a few steps:

On Windows:

1. Download a SQLite viewer, for example SQLiteStudio.
2. Find where the .db or .db3 file is stored, i did it this way:

   ```
    var databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "localDB.db3");

    Console.WriteLine(databasePath);
   ```
3. For me the path was: /data/user/0/com.companyname.[name]/files/localDB.db3
4. Find where the Android Debug Bridge (adb) .exe is stored. For me it was stored at: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools. (AppData is a hidden folder, so make sure that hidden folders are visible.
5. Open a command prompt at this folder.
6. Try to copy the database file to a local folder on your machine by entering the following line into the command prompt:

> **adb pull [path to database] [path to local folder]**

results in:

> **adb pull /data/user/0/com.companyname.[name]/files/localDB.db3 C:\Users\[user]\Desktop**

7. If you get an error "Failed to stat remote object ... Permission denied", you have to make sure you have root permission. To do this, enter the following line in the command prompt:

> **adb root**

8. Try to copy the file again.
9. If the file is succesfully copied, open it with SQLiteStudio.

et voila

Comment: adb root return:
adbd cannot run as root in production builds
?
In Debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can access the sqlite database file in xamarin forms using Rider IDE:

- Set your db path

```cs
private string GetDatabasePath()
{
    return Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "db.db");
}
```

Logging `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)` prints this path on my device

```
/data/user/0/com.companyname.landpriceexplorer/files
```

- Click the **Device File Explorer** tab on the right side.

[image]

- Search for the database file in the device file explorer.

[image]

- Double click the file to add to the data source.
- Open the **Database** tab and browse your data there.

[image]