# Unable to get correct path with Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) method in Xamarin

Tags: c#, database, xamarin, environment-variables

In Xamarin C# app I am trying to reach my database file (and find where it is located) using this code:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData),
                        "patients.db");
```

dbPath become equal to "/data/user/0/com.companyname.MobileApp/files/.local/share" which is nonsense because in tutorial it shows that path should be something like "C://Users//......"

What am I missing? Maybe I need to set any environment variables in order to use this method?

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQtNynTLhl4
And I am using Visual Studio and simulating Android device.

Comment: If you are using Android the path it returns is for the Android file system, not a path on your Windows desktop.  If you want to access an Android file from your desktop, use `adb` to extract it

Comment: It does look like your expected path is a Windows path, and the retrieved path is on another OS. Could you be more specific? On which device are you testing this out? Could you add a link to the tutorial you mention?

Comment: Note that Environment.GetFolderPath(..) delivers the requested folder with respect to the OS on which the code are running.
The one You show, indicates Android (or perhaps IOS), while the tutorial references windows.

Comment: You may need `adb pull [path to database] [path to local folder]` to get the database from your device and then view it in your windows machine. For more details, you can refer to [How to browse sqlite data in xamarin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33448255/how-to-browse-sqlite-data-in-xamarin).

Comment: I have added tutorial I follwed and what I am using

Comment: Oh I see now, in tutorial he is using Universal Windows platform apps. And I just want to create a database and use it for Android Xamarin app.

Comment: @vytaute Excellent, if you have figured out the differences between Universal Windows platform and Android when consuming the database, you can post your solution.